# Change the text next to a radio button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to javascript and I can't set the text next to the Radio button to what I want, even after trying to find everything I can online. I am sure it something simple and I would really apprecitae it if someone could help me.

Here is my HTML Element for my radio group

```
<form class="description" action ="">
  <input type="radio" id="answer0id" name="answers" value="answer0"> answer0<br>
  <input type="radio" id="answer1id" name="answers" value="answer1"> answer1<br>
  <input type="radio" id="answer2id" name="answers" value="answer2"> answer2<br>
  <input type="radio" id="answer3id" name="answers" value="answer3"> answer3<br>
</form>
```

And this is the Javascript I am trying to run to test just changing one

```
document.getElementById('answer0id').value = 'testing123';
```

I know it is probably an easy fix, but I would really appreciate anyone who could help me.

Comment: So what happens? Nothing?  Are you sure the javascript even executes?  Where are you putting it?

Comment: Actually, the text - if by that you mean the string right before the `<br>` -- isn't the value of the `input` tag.  It's a separate text node.

Comment: @adeneo Yeah, just realized that.  Will delete my suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text is just a rogue text node, as the input is self-closing and can't contain any inner text, but you can target the text node coming after the input with something like `nextSibling`

```js
document.getElementById('answer0id').nextSibling.textContent = ' testing123';
```

```html
<form class="description" action ="">
  <input type="radio" id="answer0id" name="answers" value="answer0"> answer0<br>
  <input type="radio" id="answer1id" name="answers" value="answer1"> answer1<br>
  <input type="radio" id="answer2id" name="answers" value="answer2"> answer2<br>
  <input type="radio" id="answer3id" name="answers" value="answer3"> answer3<br>
</form>
```

You could also modify the HTML to wrap the text in either a span, label or some other element that is more easily selectable.

```js
document.querySelector('#answer0id ~ label').innerHTML = 'testing123';
```

```html
<form class="description" action ="">
  <input type="radio" id="answer0id" name="answers" value="answer0" />
  <label for="answer0id">answer0</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" id="answer1id" name="answers" value="answer1" />
  <label for="answer1id">answer1</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" id="answer2id" name="answers" value="answer2" />
  <label for="answer2id">answer2</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" id="answer3id" name="answers" value="answer3" />
  <label for="answer3id">answer3</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! Weirdly now, all the text is bolded in the radio group. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Not really, some CSS must be affecting it, check your stylesheets ?

Comment: Thank you. Any idea what it would look like? Thanks so much

Comment: If the text is bold, you probably have a `font-weight` set somewhere

Answer (score 4):

I believe that `label` is what you are looking for.

**Note**: Input doesn't have `innerHTML`/`textContent` attributes since it's a non-closing tag. That's why the inventor of HTML came up with labels. What's more - you are even able to check the radio button by clicking the corresponding text.

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('label[for="answer0id"]');

elem.textContent = 'testing123';
```

```html
<form class="description" action="">
  <input type="radio" id="answer0id" name="answers" value="answer0">
  <label for='answer0id'>answer0</label><br />
  <input type="radio" id="answer1id" name="answers" value="answer1">
  <label for='answer1id'>answer1</label><br />
  <input type="radio" id="answer2id" name="answers" value="answer2">
  <label for='answer2id'>answer2</label><br />
  <input type="radio" id="answer3id" name="answers" value="answer3">
  <label for='answer3id'>answer3</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('answer0id').`**value**`= 'testing123';` refers to `<input type="radio" id="answer0id" name="answers"`**value="answer0"**`> answer0<br>`. Therefore, it does not change the text.

In your case, you can select the text via `.nextSibling.textContent` (see below). An alternative would be wrapping the text in an extra element, say `<span id="answer0-label">answer0</span>` and select that one directly.

```js
document.getElementById('answer0id').nextSibling.textContent = ' testing123';
```

```html
<form class="description" action ="">
  <input type="radio" id="answer0id" name="answers" value="answer0"> answer0<br>
  <input type="radio" id="answer1id" name="answers" value="answer1"> answer1<br>
  <input type="radio" id="answer2id" name="answers" value="answer2"> answer2<br>
  <input type="radio" id="answer3id" name="answers" value="answer3"> answer3<br>
</form>
```